# Safari blank screen issue

Tags: ios, web, server, safari

We have a website which sometimes becomes non-responding in Safari.

The issue has been occuring since November 2020 on all of the Apple devices (iPhones, iPads, Macs)
The problem is that the page starts to work vastly slower to the point when it freezes and becomes entirely blank (without any information either on the page or a console).

No requests are either sent or received, which has been verified using a proxy tool. After a while the Safari displays the notification message „**Safari cannot find server**”.
The occurrence and reproducibility is random and incoherent.

The browser functionalities stay intact (going backwards/forwards/reloading/using address bar, etc).

The page starts to work: using a private mode / after restarting the entire browser / after clearing the browser cache, memory.
We suspect that the cause lies in the Safari conditions which blocks the whole domain DNS which eventually leads to the freezes and the blank page.

- We would be grateful for any advice or a suggestion.
- The site runs properly on non-Apple devices and browsers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Good first question! I sounds it could be helpful to run memory profiling and add the result here. [WebKit documentation](https://webkit.org/blog/6425/memory-debugging-with-web-inspector/)